Riverpod provider auto-disposed even if the widget using it is on screen
I am passing arguments to my provider like
@riverpod
class FetchProducts extends _$FetchProducts {
  @override
  Future<List<Product>> build({
    required String? specificProductId,
    required String? clientUid,
  }) async {
    List<Product> _productList = [];

    if (specificProductId != null) {
      final productDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('product')
          .doc(specificProductId.trim())
          .get();
      if (productDataSnapshot.exists && productDataSnapshot.data() != null) {
        _productList.add(Product.fromMap(productDataSnapshot.data()!));
      }
    } else if (clientUid != null && clientUid != '') {
      final productDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('product')
          .where('client_uid', isEqualTo: clientUid)
          .get();
      print(productDataSnapshot.docs.map((data) => data.data()));
      for (var pdt in productDataSnapshot.docs) {
        _productList.add(Product.fromMap(pdt.data()));
      }
    } else {
      final productDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').get();
      for (var pdt in productDataSnapshot.docs) {
        _productList.add(Product.fromMap(pdt.data()));
      }
    }

    return _productList;
  }

  Future<void> createNewProduct(Product pdtData) async {
    final newPdt = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').add(pdtData.toMap());
    Product newProduct = Product.fromMap(newPdt as Map<String, dynamic>);
    state = AsyncData([...?state.value, newProduct]);
  }
}

As soon as my UI page opens all products are fetched by a widget with both specificProductId and clientUid as null/empty.
final productList = ref.watch(fetchProductsProvider(clientUid: null, specificProductId: null));
There is another notifier provider which gives clientUid when a client is chosen in UI. This triggers a widget on the same UI page to fetch products for that specific clientUid.
ref.watch(FetchProductsProvider(specificProductId: null, clientUid: widget.clientUid));
However, this causes the provider with all the products i.e. productList getting disposed off.
Problem: How to keep the state of the provider with all the products intact when provider is watched by any other widget with different set of parameters, but auto-disposing the provider when the last listener has been removed?
Current Console output looks like -

Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#80775(null) was initialized with
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>()
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#80775(null) updated from
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>() to AsyncData<List<Product>>(value: [Instance of 'Product',
Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product'])

// Chosing a client from Dropdown in UI

Provider chosenClientUidProvider:AutoDisposeNotifierProviderImpl<ChosenClientUid,
String?>#d6c1c updated from  to 8C9rnBB2sNk0
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#4e744(null) was initialized with
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>()
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#80775(null) was disposed
Provider fetchProductsProvider:FetchProductsProvider#4e744(null) updated from
AsyncLoading<List<Product>>() to AsyncData<List<Product>>(value: [Instance of 'Product',
Instance of 'Product', Instance of 'Product'])


